# Discrete type random variables and probability mass functions.

Tags: probability, combinatorics, random-variables

Situation: 3 dice are rolled. Calculate the pmf of X, given that X is the event that a 3 shows.

I started out by identifying the probable events of X, which are X = {0, 1, 2, 3}, these represent the number of 3's that show from the 3 rolled dice.

What I'm having trouble with is calculating these individual probabilities.

I know there are 6^3 = 216 possible scenarios for the rolled dice, but I don't know if

P(X = 0) = 5^3/216 & P(X = 3) = 1/216 are correct, and I'm unsure of the other 2 probabilities.

Comment: Please clarify: If $X$ is the **event** that a three shows, then it takes the boolean values of $\{T, F\}$.  If $X$ is the **random variable** of the count of threes that show, then it takes the integer values of $\{0, 1, 2, 3\}$.  So which is $X$, an *event* or a *random variable*.

Answer (score 0):

> Situation: 3 dice are rolled. Calculate the pmf of X, given that X is the event that a 3 shows.

**Please clarify:** If $X$ is the **event** that a three shows, then it takes the boolean values of $\{\mathrm T,\mathrm F\}$ . If $X$  is the **random variable** counting threes that show, then it takes the integer values of ${0,1,2,3}\$ .

---

The probability of the **event** that a three shows is the complement of the probability that a three does not show.  $$\begin{align}\mathsf P(X^c) & = (\tfrac 5 6)^3 \\[1ex] & = \frac {125} {216}\\[3ex] \mathsf P(X) & = 1 - \mathsf P(X^c)\\[1ex] & = \frac{91}{216}\end{align}$$

Hence the probability mass function of the **event** is: $$p_X(x) = \begin{cases} 125/216 & : x \equiv \top \\ 91/216 & : x\equiv \bot \end{cases}$$

---

*However*, if the question mean that $X$ was the **random variable** counting threes that show, then we model this as a binomial distribution.

$$p_X(k) = \begin{cases} \binom{3}{k} (\tfrac 5 6)^{3-k}(\tfrac 1 6)^k & : k\in \{0,1,2,3\} \\ 0 & :\text{elsewhere}\end{cases}$$

Then the individual probabilities are:
$$\begin{align}p_X(0) & = \frac {5^3}{6^3} \\ p_X(1) & = \frac{3\times 5^2}{6^3}\\ p_X(2) & = \frac{3\times 5}{6^3} \\ p_X(3) & = \frac{1}{6^3} \end{align}$$

---

So which is $X$ , an event or a random variable?

Comment: So sorry. You're correct on X being a random variable. I worded the question incorrectly. Thank you. However, may I ask, why you are multiplying by 3?

Comment: @OmarAyala It's the binomial coefficient in the binomial distribution equation: $\binom{3}{1}=3$